# How do I implement the Midpoint Line Generation Algorithm to include cases where x1 > x2 or y1 > y2?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Let's say I have a canvas of 20 x 20 pixels. Now let's say I have the starting point as (x1, y1) = (12, 3) and (x2, y2) = (9, 16). In this case, x1 > x2. I am confused on how I adjust the midpoint algorithm to account for this case. My approach consists of swapping the two coordinate values so that x1, y1 = x2, y2 however it only goes diagonally and does not go straight for some reason. Here's my code in JavaScript:

```
{
    let dx = Math.abs(x2 - x1);
    let dy = Math.abs(y2 - y1);
    let d = dy - dx/2;

    if (x1 > x2) {
        [x1, x2] = [x2, x1];
        [y1, y2] = [y2, y1];
    }

    let sy = (y1 < y2 ? 1 : -1);

    if (dx > dy) {
        while (x1 < x2) {
            x1++;

            if (d < 0)
                d += dy;
            else {
                d += (dy - dx);
                y1 += sy;
            }

            console.log(x1 + ',' + y1)
        }
    } else {
        while (y1 !== y2) {
            x1++;

            if (d < 0)
                d += dy;
            else {
                d += (dy - dx);
                y1 += sy;
            }

            console.log(x1 + ',' + y1)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appretiated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can [Linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) these points like this:

```
P1+0.5*(P2-P1)
```

In your case:

```
(12;3) + 0.5 * [(9;16)-(12;3)] = (10.5;9.5)
```